# Gravity breaks the first law of thermodynamics what?

Tags: gravity

If there was a system where there is a light emitter (such as the sun) how is something such as light not violating the first law of thermodynamics by escaping the gravity of the sun with no Δv.
We know light has mass since it behaves as a particle sometimes and through object tests such as a Crookes radiometer.

My teach said, "For classical physics "particle" means an entity with small mass and a center of mass tracked at coordinates (x,y,z) at time t. Solutions of kinematic differential equations described the trajectory with accuracy determined by experimental errors."
This proves that light, being a particle has mass.

Comment: What do you mean by "what is giving the gravitational force that speed?" Forces don't have speeds.

Comment: Note: the [Crookes radiometer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crookes_radiometer) is a heat engine, not directly sensitive to photon pressure.

Comment: This paragraph is written in a stream of consciousness style. You would likely get a friendlier response to your question if you put some effort into structuring your question logically so it is clear to people what you are assuming, what you know, and exactly what your question is, with no extraneous details or speculation.

Comment: I changed the question a bit. Is this better. Also hello again rob sorry I keep making kind of bad posts

Answer (score 3):

A few comments.

First, (as pointed about by joseph h), light does not have mass. It does have momentum. You may have learned that the momentum $p$, mass $m$, and velocity $v$ of a particle are related by $p=mv$. However, this formula is only valid in classical, non-relativistic physics (where things move much slower than light), and does not apply to light. A photon with wavelength $\lambda$ has momentum $p=h/\lambda$, where $h$ is Planck's constant and $\lambda$ is the wavelength.

Second, the trajectory of a light ray is bent by a gravitational field. This is called [gravitational lensing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_lens). In a sense, you can think of it as light being deflected by a gravitational force. Using general relativity, a more modern way to look at it is that light is following a path that is as straight as possible in a curved spacetime.

Third, when you raise the question about how the gravitational force can travel fast enough to catch up with a light ray, I think you are hitting on something interesting. The gravitational field is a *force field* that is present in all of space. Light responds to the gravitational field at its location; the *force* does not travel (the words "force traveling" don't make much sense), because the force is determined by an interaction between the light and the gravitational field at the light's location. However, disturbances in the field do propagate at a finite speed (the speed of light, for gravity). Say there is a star, then the gravitational field near the star will bend light due to gravitational lensing. If the star were to suddenly disappear at time $t$ (or if you want to be more physical, we can say it suddenly accelerates very quickly at time $t$), then the field a distance $r$ away from the star would only change at time $t+r/c$. In other words, a light ray passing a distance $r$ from the star would continue to be bend as if the star was there, until enough time passed that a "ripple" in the gravitational field traveling at $c$ has had time to travel from the star to $r$.

Finally, you are right that a light ray will gain energy as it falls into a gravitational field, much like a rock dropped will gain kinetic energy as it falls. You are also right that this gain in energy is related to the wavelength of the light. In particular, the wavelength of the light will decrease. Because of the equation $E = h f$, where $E$ is the photon energy, $h$ is Planck's constant, and $f$ is the frequency (which is related the wavelength via $f \lambda = c$), the energy of the photon will increase. The reverse effect, where a light ray climbing out of a gravitational field loses energy, is known as [gravitational redshift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_redshift).

Comment: well at least my assumption about the wavelength was right lol

Answer (score 1):

First, a *Crookes radiometer* is actually a *heat engine* and its behaviour is [thermodynamic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crookes_radiometer). I made the same mistake by assuming that its rotation was due to the imparting of momentum by incident light. In fact, that was originally how the devices’ rotation was originally explained and was agreed upon by Maxwell himself, so don’t feel bad. Rob has corrected this error in a comment below. But:

It's not clear why you think gravity violates the first law of thermodynamics (as per the title of your question). It does not.

Light has *no mass* and *always* travels with the same speed, c. It doesn’t interact with gravity that way, but because light has *energy and momentum*. Light follows paths called *geodesics* and these paths are determined by the gravitational field.

That is, the spacetime in the region of massive bodies is curved, and objects move in this spacetime along geodesic paths. Also, note that even though light has no mass, it still has momentum given by $p=\frac Ec$. And light moving through a curved spacetime (and in a Minkowski spacetime) still travels at the same velocity and gravity does not change this velocity.

All of this is explained in Einstein's theory of general relativity and if you are a physics student in college, you may consider taking a class in it, as it seems you're genuinely interested in it.

Comment: Note: the [Crookes radiometer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crookes_radiometer) is a heat engine, not directly sensitive to photon momentum.

Comment: Thanks for that.

Comment: so light is not a form of matter?

Comment: @Fakhryou no, it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

When studying physics, one must have a very clear understanding that all physics theories are valid in a given phase-space of variables, and only conservation laws have to be obeyed in all variable phase-spaces/frames.

In the case of gravity, there exists the classical Newtonian theory and in the case of light, classical electrodynamics. To solve your problem in a consistent way, one must remain in this classical frame. Mixing up frames brings paradoxes that are fake. In the classical frame light caries energy and momentum as formulated with the Poynting vector, and there is no problem with energy and momentum conservation in calculations in this frame, and no break of any thermodynamic law. Note that thermodynamics is also within the classical frame.

Photons belong to the quantum mechanical frame, and carry energy and momentum according to the [four vectors](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/vec4.html) describing them in special relativity.

\begin{equation*}
\sqrt{P \cdot P} = \sqrt{E^2-(pc)^2}=m_0 c^2
\end{equation*}

Their mass is zero but this does not prevent them from having energy and momentum as seen by the formula which has been validated by innumerable experiments.

Then enter the problems of the description of gravity at the quantum level. If one is in a frame where general relativity effects can be ignored as too small, the photon energy and momentum when it impinges on the gravitational mass is transferred to the final atoms that it interacts with on hitting the mass, thus the momentum and energy of the mass increase by that amount.

If masses are such that general relativity, instead of special , has to be invoked the problem of  the geometric factors enter as in @joseph' answer. If in addition one has quantization of gravity, there will be a quantum mechanical interaction of the photon with the graviton that will lie in the basis of the interaction.

The basic thing is that conservation of energy and momentum are assumed in all quantum mechanical interactions, so again the energy and momentum will be transferred to the gravitational mass. There is always mathematical consistency going from one theoretical frame to another.